# "Smooth" integral probability metric

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory, statistics

[Integral probability metrics](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.2698.pdf) is a popular choice of family of semi-metrics on the probability measures: For a measurable space $(X, \mathcal{X})$ and a family $\mathcal{F}$ of real-valued bounded measurable functions on $X$, the integral probability metric is defined as
$$
d_{\mathcal{F}}(\mathbb{P}, \mathbb{Q}) = \sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \left| \int_X f \, \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P} - \int_X f \, \mathrm{d}\mathbb{Q} \right|.
$$
For example, if $\mathcal{F}$ consists of functions $f$ such that $\lVert f \rVert_\infty \le 1$, then $d_\mathcal{F}$ is the [total variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures).

Is there a "smooth" version of the integral probability metric? Intuitively, how $L_1$ norm is different from sup-norm on a class of real-valued functions. Suppose we induce a probability measure $\mu$ on the set $\mathcal{F}$ (with some suitable choice of $\sigma-$algebra), then we can define:
$$
D_{\mathcal{F}}(\mathbb{P}, \mathbb{Q}) = \int_\mathcal{F} \left| \int_X f \, \mathrm{d}\mathbb{P} - \int_X f \, \mathrm{d}\mathbb{Q} \right| \; \mathrm{d}\mu(f).
$$
If yes, can somebody point me to some resources where I can read about their properties?

Comment: If you take $\mathcal{F} = \{f_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, a countable famility of continuous functions that act seperating on the set of probability measures and set $\mu(\{f_n\}):=2^{-n}$ you get back the weak-*-convergence, that metrizes the usual "weak" convergence of probability measures

Comment: If $X$ is compact the probability measures are compact Hausdorff with this weak-*-topology (Banach-Alaoglu). If two compact Hausdorff topologies are compareable (w.r.t. set-theoretic inclusion) then they are equal. That suggests that you probably won't new "interesting" topologies, but maybe interesting metrics for that topology.